# How to use nginx (intsalled on Docker) to reverse proxy MySQL (installed on Docker too)

Tags: mysql, docker, nginx

Here is docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - /lnmpg/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro,cached
      - /lnmpg/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf :ro
      - /lnmpg/nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
      - /lnmpg/nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "33060:3306"
    environment:
        - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-mysql
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7.41
      # ports:
      # - "3307:3306"
      environment:
          - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Xqw@1023
      volumes:
          - /lnmpg/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
          - /lnmpg/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf :ro
          - /lnmpg/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
          - /lnmpg/mysql/log:/var/log/mysql 
      restart: always
      networks:
        - nginx-mysql
```

And here is `nginx.conf`

```
stream {
    log_format basic '$remote_addr [$time_local] '
                     '$protocol $status $bytes_sent $bytes_received '
                     '$session_time';
    access_log logs/stream-access.log debug buffer=32k;
    server {
        listen 33060;
        proxy_pass mysql:3306;
           }  
       }

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I don't know what went wrong,just could not connect to mysql with port `33060` of the host.If I cancel the ports comment in docker-compose.yml, I can access it normally with `3307`.These two containers are under the same network: `nginx-mysql`,so `mysql:3306` in the `nginx.conf` should be recognized by the docker container as `mysql's ip:3306` Did I misunderstand the function of the `network` or my configuration files were wrong? By the way these two dockers are in one docker-composer file.So `networks` is not necessary,Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing should work. I can spot a small error though, and that is that you map port 3306 on the Nginx container, but it listens on port 33060. I think I'd make Nginx listen on 3306, by changing the line in the config file to

```
listen 3306;
```

If you prefer, you can also change the docker-compose file, so it maps port 33060 in the container instead.

I can't spot what's wrong with your files, but here is a minimal setup that works:

nginx.conf

```
events { }

stream {
  server {
    listen 3306;
    proxy_pass mysql:3306;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=myrootpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Run and test with

```
docker-compose up -d
docker run --rm --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway mysql mysql -h host.docker.internal -u myuser -pmypassword -e "show databases;"
```

Comment: tried changing the listening port of nginx to 3306, and changed the port mapping to "3306:3306", but it still does'nt work.

Comment: I can't spot what's wrong with your files. I've added my minimal setup that I used to test it. I hope you can work with that to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: finally figure out the reason. ` :ro` ,There should not have a space in front of `:ro`

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this. `nginx` is mainly a proxy for *HTTP* (hypertext transfer protocol). It won't help you connecting to a totally different protocol like MYSQL's.

Maybe you can explain in your question why you are trying to proxy MySQL access in the first place.

Comment: I just saw someone did that,besides ,they said doing this is more safety for databases.And sometimes the database cannot be directly accessed from the internet,so  they need a jump server,just like nginx.In fact, I'm also curious, is it really necessary to do this?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html

Comment: Thanks @StupidPz
Did not know that. Looging into it right now.